# call js function from php but property not found

Tags: javascript, php, dom-manipulation

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null when calling js function test().
What is wrong with this example code?
Is there a better way to call a js function from php for DOM Manipulation?

html

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    <input type="text" id="inp">Test</input>
    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></button>
</form>
```

php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit')]
{
    $wrongInput= some code...

    if ($wrongInput)
    {
        echo "<script src=main.js></script>";
        echo "<script type=text/javascript>test();</script>"
    }
}
```

js

```
function test()
{
    document.querySelector("#submit").style.background = "red";
}
```

Comment: Missing quotes ? `src=main.js`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette  should not be the problem. Calling the function test() works but the dom manipulation does not...

Comment: Probably the function is called before the DOM is loaded then.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette that would be also  my guess. But I don´t know how to fix that. should I use a setTimeout function for waiting the dom until it is loaded? what is the best way?

Comment: You cannot call javascript functions directly from PHP.  The code will be sent to the browser once the page is sent and run as it would be as part of the page loading.

Comment: add `differ` to your script tags

Comment: @medilies: you mean `defer`... lol! [defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I really needed some IntelliSense on the comment textarea XD

Comment: @NigelRen well, calling the function test() works. if I put an alert() in the function test(), it executes but the property of #submit is not set yet...

Comment: It will eventually be executed, I said that it will be output to the browser and then executed. This doesn't mean it's executed at the time you run the PHP code.

Comment: @medilies unfortunately defer did not work for me...

Comment: @NigelRen yeah, that is probably right but how do I solve this problem? using setTimeout for my test function or is there a better way?

Comment: put " ' " here: $wrongInput= some code...
$wrongInput= "some code..."
and 
echo "<script defer type='text/javascript'>test();</script>"

Comment: Try `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ test() })` or even better `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", test )`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette perfect, you saved me !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unclear where that is being echoed in the page... But for sure, the DOM needs to be loaded for the `querySelector` to find the element. So the use of the `DOMContentLoaded` event is the way to make sure, disregarding where the echo is. ;)

```php
if(isset($_POST['submit')]
{
    $wrongInput= //some code...

    if ($wrongInput)
    {
        echo "<script src='main.js'></script>";
        echo "<script>document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', test);</script>";
    }
}
```